# Abelian group proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $2Z$ be the set of even integer numbers. Consider the operation $⊥$ defined by placing, for every $a, b ∈ 2Z$,

$a ⊥ b = a + b - 2$.

• Prove that the algebraic structure $(2Z, ⊥)$ is an abelian group, highlighting in particular what is the neutral element and what is the symmetric of each element $a ∈ 2Z$.

I think the structure isn't an abelian group because subtraction ($-2$ in this case) is not associative. Please tell me what you think.

Comment: This is a common type of exercise involving deriving a new group operation from an old one. If $(G,+)$ is an Abelian group and $g$ is a fixed element of $G$ then $a*b=a+b+g$ defines another Abelian group operation on $G$.

Comment: For Abelian criterion you have to check commutativity and yes in this case $a*b=b*a$

Comment: The requirement from the definition of group is not that ${}-{}$ is associative.  You must check that $\bot$ is associative.

Answer (score 1):

$$a\perp(b\perp c)=a\perp(b+c-2)=a+(b+c-2)-2=a+b+c-4$$

$$(a\perp b)\perp c=(a+b-2)\perp c=(a+b-2)+c-2=a+b+c-4$$
So yes: the operation is associative. Observe that the operations on the right side of the definition of $\;a\perp b\;$ are the *usual* operations on the integers.

Now try to check the other axioms (closedness is immediate, though)

Comment: What's the neutral element and how do I find it?

Comment: Solve the equation $a\bot e=a$  for $e$.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen what do I need to do to prove that the structure is an abelian group?

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen So the neutral element is 2?

Comment: @JohnD Yes, it is.

Comment: @DonAntonio how can I prove that the structure is an abelian group?

Comment: @JohnD Read your notes...Prove the operation is closed, commutative, associative (proved in my answer) and you have a neutral element

Comment: @DonAntonio How can I prove that it's closed and commutative? (I don't have notes)